# Access WinAPI through the powershell from a WSH JScript?

Tags: powershell, winapi, jscript, wsh

I'd like to acces some WinAPI functions from a JScript that runs on the Windows Script Host.
Since that is not possible directly, I'd like to do it using the powershell.
I don't want to spawn a new powershell process everytime I access a WinAPI function, so I'm looking for a way to spawn one hidden powershell instance from JScript and keep using that for all my API calls.

Has anyone tried something like that before?
I'd really like to see a simple example on something simple like [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx).
Is there a COM interface to efficiently communicate with the powershell?

I also have some more advaced questions...
How could I pass a callback function to a WinAPI function, so that my JScript function gets called whenever the WinAPI calls that callback?
What about other complicated, but commonly seem datatypes in the WinAPI like structs? 
And what about passing/receiving binary data?

I'd really like to see any proofs of concept and ideas you have for that...

Comment: what about using a 3rd party WinAPI Wrapper COM library instead of 
PowerShell?

Comment: No, I want this to work without third party tools.  I want the scripts to be able to simply run on any Windows machine.

Comment: PowerShell is installed by default starting from Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, until then PowerShell was also a 3rd party.
so you cannot guarantee that your script will work flawlessly on Windows XP, Server 2003, Server 2003 R2, Vista and Server 2008.

Comment: Well, that sucks, but that's still better than having to install third party software on every computer. The project I'm currently working on is mostly targeted at Windows 10 anways...